# Virtual Machine Converter 3.1 Cannot find Thumbprint

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm attempting to use the Virtual Machine Converter 3.1 to convert a VM to Azure VM.  I am following the steps here:
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn874004.aspx
 and I have created a management certificate using the instructions here:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg551722.aspx
 and I have uploaded this to my Azure Subscription.  I have verified that the certificate is in my Personal Store, and I have even copied this to the Local Machine Store.  Both Certificates show that they have private keys as expected and the certificate uploaded and shows in the Azure Management Certificates as well.

When I run the MVMC and I provide the Subscription ID and the Certificate Thumbprint I get the message: "No certificate exists with thumbprint XXXXXXXXXXXX...".  I cannot get past this screen to successfully migrate the VM to Azure, does anyone have a recommendation or suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I thought I would post the answer to help whoever finds this. ;)

From: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977336

"Certificate thumbprint is not found in the personal certificate store" error when you try to migrate to Microsoft Azure using Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

- Start the MMC.exe process.
- Click File, click Add/Remove Snap-in, and then click Certificates.
- On the Certificates snap-in screen, click Add, and then select My user account. Click Finish, and then click OK.
- Expand Console Root, expand Certificates - Current User, expand Personal, and then expand Certificates.
- Right-click your Microsoft Azure certificate. By default, this is named Microsoft Azure Tools. Select All Tasks, and then click Export.
- Click Next, and then click No, do not export the private key. Click Next.
- On the Certificate Export Wizard screen, click DER encoded X.509 (.CER), and then click Next.
- Type a file name, click Next, and then click Finish.
- Expand Console Root\Certificates - Current User, expand Trusted Root Certification Authorities, and then expand Certificates.
- Right-click Certificates, and then click Import.
- Click Next, and then locate the file that you exported in step 8.
- Follow the steps in the wizard to complete the import process. Verify that the Microsoft Azure Tools certificate now appears in both the Personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities stores.
- Return to MVMC, and then retry the Azure Connection task.